# Does Visual C++ support loop unswitching?

Tags: c, visual-c++, optimization

I'm trying to establish whether Visual C++ 2008 or 2010 supports the [loop unswitching compiler optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching). I know that gcc supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, "No":

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/126756-lack-compiler-loop-optimization-loop-unswitching.html

Your mileage might vary, depending on:

- Whether or not you have the latest compiler (MSVS 2010)
- Whether or not you've purchased MSVS Professional or higher

Comment: AFAIK the compiler optimizations available are not dependent on what version of MSVC you've bought. They add more IDE features to the more expensive versions.

Comment: I only have the free Express versions and assumed the differences with pricier versions would be fancy stuff like IDE rather than the compiler itself. But @paulsm4: [seems to be right!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271022(VS.60).aspx)

Comment: @hippietrail: note that the page you've linked applies to VC++ 6.0 (a circa 1998 compiler).

Comment: Afaik VC++ doesn't use strict aliasing rules and as I see it that's a necessary condition for this optimisation to work isn't it? I'll try it later with VS2010.

Comment: @hippietrail: According to my notes, MS released compilers that did not support optimization with the "Standard" versions of VS.NET 2002 (7.0) and VS.NET 2003 (7.1).  Since then (starting with VS 2005) all releases of the C++ compiler have had optimization support (including those in the free VC++ Express versions).

Answer (score 1):

So I just tried it with VS2010:

```
void foo(int* x, int* y, int length, int w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i] + y[i];
        if (w) {
            y[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int x[1000];
    int y[1000];
    int w;
    scanf("%d", &w);
    foo(x, y, 1000, w);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (y[i])
            sum++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

A bit more complex than necessary to make sure it doesn't optimize the function away. Anyways this results in the following disassembly:

```
PUBLIC  ?foo@@YAXPAH0HH@Z               ; foo
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ?foo@@YAXPAH0HH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
?foo@@YAXPAH0HH@Z PROC                  ; foo, COMDAT
; _x$ = ecx
; _y$ = eax
; _w$ = esi
; Line 12
    sub ecx, eax
    mov edx, 1000               ; 000003e8H
    push    edi
$LL4@foo:
; Line 10
    mov edi, DWORD PTR [eax]
    add DWORD PTR [ecx+eax], edi
; Line 11
    test    esi, esi
    je  SHORT $LN3@foo
; Line 12
    mov DWORD PTR [eax], 0
$LN3@foo:
; Line 9
    add eax, 4
    dec edx
    jne SHORT $LL4@foo
    pop edi
; Line 15
    ret 0
?foo@@YAXPAH0HH@Z ENDP                  ; foo
```

Compiled as a Release project, 32bit under VS2010 Premium, Win7 x64.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't do it but I'm rusty at assembly and never did read Intel assembly so well.

Comment: Sorry I somehow forgot to analyze the assembly - talk about empathetic ;) But yeah we have one loop (that always tests for w inside). It's actually the code between `push edi` and `pop edi` and the `test esi, esi` is the part where we test for w being 0 (if it is jump over the next mov instruction).

Comment: Note that since there's some discussion about different optimizations depending on the actual version: This was run on VS2010 Premium..